# Tool to create 3d programs

Tags: java, 3d

As we know that we can use NetBeans for creating Swing programs (with drag and drop the code for each part of Swing will be written automatically)

Is there any software that help us write Java 3d code without writing code manually?

Comment: learning to actually write code might also help...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything out there like that for almost any languages. The problem is... what exactly are you creating? With swing you know you are making a GUI for a certain set of applications but with 3D, the applications are endless. The only thing out there are APIs to help with your job. If you are an animator or game maker there are plenty of game engines to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Widening your question slightly if what you're looking for is a more productive 3D java environment (rather than Java 3D itself) then Demicron's [WireFusion](http://www.demicron.com/wirefusion/) is worth a look.  It's Java based and the higher-end versions allow pretty comprehensive access to the underlying engine so you can effectively extend it to do nearly anything.

I've used it for a project or two and I highly recommend it, the only issue is it's ridiculously expensive - in fact jaw-drop'ingly so.